# Can I change distance between icon and item title in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, menu, navigation, icons, drawer

I display next items on my navigation menu:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/nav_locate"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_add_location_black_24dp"
   android:title="Localizare" />

  <item android:id="@+id/nav_propose"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_landscape_black_24dp"
android:title="Obiective" />

  <item android:id="@+id/nav_propose"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings_black_24dp"
android:title="Setari" />

</menu>
```

But I don't like distance between icon and text. To big. Can I set my own distance between these two things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i don't think there is any direct ways to do that, you can inflate custom layout directly to navigation drawer. From the custom layout, you can do anything you want. The idea is, you make list items that contain ImageView and TextView, and you can set the distance(margin or padding) directly to them.

Here is the example of DrawerLayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Main content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Insert any views you want as main content -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here how you inflate your custom layout

```
RelativeLayout drawer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
View drawerContent = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_content, null);
drawerContent.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
drawer.addView(drawerContent);
```

Now you create `drawer_content.xml` inside `res/layout` and make the layout as you wish.
Here is the example of `drawer_content.xml` that you can make

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Menu 1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Menu 2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Menu 3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: menu is painted in a gray window. And get error here   android:src="@drawable/ic_menu1" />

Comment: You supposed to have ic_menu1 inside your drawable directory. And about the gray window, you can set background directly to the content LinearLayout or the container RelativeLayout with `android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"`